# GattServiceProvider DeviceInformation Service

Tags: uwp, gatt

so we publish our own service with the new Windows 10 GATT Server API.
According to the "documentation" on MSDN the DIS is on the list of restricted services.

Windows actually publishes the DIS automatically as the first primary service.
But it only provides the PnP characteristic. We need a few different ones as well.

Creating it again with GattServiceProvider.CreateAsync results in a DisabledByPolicy error as described in the documentation.

Is there a way to get windows to publish the other characteristics as well ? (model, manufacturer, serial...) or is there a way to access the service that windows is publishing automatically to add those manually?

Best regards,
Marcus

Comment: Where is the "documentation"? How do you implement your server? Please refer the [BluetoothLE](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/BluetoothLE) sample and the [Bluetooth GATT Server](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/devices-sensors/gatt-server) document.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But that is the documentation I was talking about. It is OK to implement our own service, which we have done. And while it has some unique behaviour to it, GattServiceProvider does its job and works fine. The question is about adding or augmenting what it publishes for the DIS. Both the sample and documentation do not mention the DIS, except for the documentation saying it is on the list of "restricted services" but no mention that it will get published automatically and how to access/modify it

Comment: You are not able to modify the DIS data.  It is automatically published by Windows and cannot be changed by an app.

Comment: Well that is suboptimal. On every other platform you can either publish the DIS at will or at least indirectly control what the content of the different DIS characteristics is. Windows only publishes the PnP characteristic. This is rather unfortunate but thank you for your answer.